# Bypassing VPN restriction in another app

Tags: vpn

I want to know if its possible to trick this app "Diitalk" into either thinking I am in US or blocking it from knowing that my VPN is working cuz if I dont have a US based IP, it wont let me use the US based number.

[image]
*(Click on image to enlarge)*

Can this be done on the android device itself without having to use a VPN router or any other device?

[image]
*(Click on image to enlarge)*

Comment: Robert has explained it thoroughly. I have gotten similar experience before. While using LetsVPN I get restricted by most apps but then I switched to OpenVPN and boom, problem solved. I think you should also try a new VPN instead.

Answer (score 1):

VPN detection is usually done on server side.

Diitalk simply has to check your IP and compare it to a list of IP ranges by common VPN providers. If the IP is in the IP range of a known VPN provider it blocks you. This is known as blacklisting.

Therefore the highest change to bypass such a VPN check is to use a custom server and install your own VPN on it. If the server's IP is not in a range used frequently for VPN your VPN may stay undetected.

However the service you are trying to use may use a different VPN detection technique, like whitelisting. The IP ranges from US telecomunication providers are known and one can simply check if the IP is within a range or not. In such a case any VPN provider or self-installed VPN will fail.

Comment: Is it possible for me to obtain a US based IP without having to use VPN?

Comment: The only chance I see is buying a SIM card from a US mobile network provider and then use it where ever you live. Using the mobile network roaming you should get an IP from the MNO home network (which is in the US as it is an US provider). Note that with an "US MNO" am not referring to an MNO of the same name in your country. You have to buy it directly from the US MNO!

Comment: I dont know if its allowed to be humorous here but...

Comment: Wouldnt it be odd if I purchase a US based SIM to get another virtual number

Comment: Your question was about VPN, not about phone numbers...

Comment: Thats true sir.

Comment: Any luck you would tell me about them as well

Comment: If I would know one, yes. May be someone else has a different idea, but these are the options I know.

Comment: I think the app is able to assess that a VPN is in use through the VPN network setting. Can I stop that?